# Always rounding down a number

Tags: java, math, rounding

I would like to know how I can instruct Java to always round down a given number.

E.g:

```
1.08 rounds to 1
1.88 rounds to 1
1.999999999999 rounds to 1
0.0002 rounds to 0
123.77 rounds to 123
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Math.floor is the function you are looking for.

Comment: Check the [java.lang.Math API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) you should be able to find the method you need in there.

Answer (score 8):

That's what [`Math#floor` does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29):

> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Math.floor(double)` instead of `Math.round(double)`

Or you can just cast if you want to round towards 0

```
double d = 1.999999999999;
long l = (long) d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.floor function will do the trick.

Takes a double, Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.

If you need it in a different form just cast it after (ie int)

The specs are here if you are curious how it works: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

if you need an example let me know and ill hook you up :)